# Zend Framework 2 how to test redirect in controller action?

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

How can I test a redirect in a controller action with PHPUnit?

```
class IndexControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected $_controller;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_routeMatch;
    protected $_event;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->_controller = new IndexController;
        $this->_request = new Request;
        $this->_response = new Response;
        $this->_routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
        $this->_routeMatch->setMatchedRouteName('default');
        $this->_event = new MvcEvent();
        $this->_event->setRouteMatch($this->_routeMatch);
        $this->_controller->setEvent($this->_event);
    }

    public function testIndexActionRedirectsToLoginPageWhenNotLoggedIn()
    {
        $this->_controller->dispatch($this->_request, $this->_response);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->_response->getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

The above code causes this error when I run unit tests:

```
Zend\Mvc\Exception\DomainException: Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found
```

It's because I am doing a redirect inside the controller action. If I don't do a redirect, unit tests work. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems pretty much like an indirect duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570377/how-can-i-pass-extra-parameters-to-the-routematch-object

Comment: I'd suggest looking at how to instantiate the router object and then add it to the MvcEvent as the URL plugin requires this. I’d imagine a good starting point would be the SimpleRouteStack class as that implements the interface which is being checked for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I needed to do in the setUp:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->_controller = new IndexController;
    $this->_request = new Request;
    $this->_response = new Response;

    $this->_event = new MvcEvent();

    $routeStack = new SimpleRouteStack;
    $route = new Segment('/admin/[:controller/[:action/]]');
    $routeStack->addRoute('admin', $route);
    $this->_event->setRouter($routeStack);

    $routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));
    $routeMatch->setMatchedRouteName('admin');
    $this->_event->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);

    $this->_controller->setEvent($this->_event);
}
```